# Parsing double quotes (") and ampersand (&) in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, asp-classic

Using the following code:

```
<script language="javascript">
<![CDATA[
// content of your Javascript goes here
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#txtModel").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({url: "searchIModel.asp", dataType: "json", data: {term: request.term, itembrand: $("#txtBrand").val(), test: 85},
          success: function(data) { response(data); }
        });
      },
        minLength:1});
  });
]]>
</script>
```

The classic ASP is called and a JSON data are returned but double quotes and ampersand (&) are not filtered and is rendering the returned value cut short. Any solution to this?

This is the classic ASP page. What is in here actually is to receive a JSON data.

```vbs
<%
Function UpCase(StringtoBeUppercase) 
    UpCase = UCase(Trim(StringtoBeUppercase))
End Function
'start initializing popup window for models
Dim iBrand, iModel, mdlResult, stat, ctr
usrID = session("userSession")
action = trim(request.QueryString("test"))
if action = "85" then
  iBrand = UpCase(request.QueryString("itembrand"))
  iModel = UpCase(request.QueryString("term"))
  if trim(iModel) <> "" then
        stat = skuObj.searchIModel(iBrand,iModel,iDesc,usrID)
  end if
  'if there are matches to the query; extract 10 recordset more
  if trim(stat) ="00" then
    'generate a JSON-type string result
    mdlResult = "[{""id"":""" & "model0" & """,""value"":""" & trim(iModel) & """},"
    for ctr = 1 to 10
      stat = skuObj.searchIModel(iBrand,iModel,iDesc,usrID)
      if stat <> "00" then
        exit for
      else
        mdlResult = mdlResult & "{""id"":""" & "model" & CStr(ctr) & """,""value"":""" & trim(iModel) & """},"
      end if
    next

    mdlResult=left(mdlResult,len(mdlResult)-1)
    mdlResult = mdlResult & "]"
    response.write(mdlResult)
  end if
end if
%>
```

What was returned here are bits and pieces of data that has, say models;

SONIC

SONYEBC

SONY & ABC    --> this needs parsing (&)

SYNJUCO

SYNJUCO "BELL"  --> this needs parsing ("")

TENKO

Any solution to this?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing what's actually returned.  You're saying the bug is in your ASP code, but you're showing us JavaScript?  If you're not returning proper JSON, it's unlikely that it is salvageable.  Without proper escaping, reserved JSON characters are ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding the value you are printing to the output.

`response.write(Server.HTMLEncode(mdlResult))`

[Server.HTMLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: It wont be able to HTMLEncode it because I am returning JSON data formatted string.

Comment: how about encoding only the values then ? `Server.HTMLEncode(trim(iModel))`